# How to reset forms from another unrelated component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I got several (template-driven-forms) in my application and want to reset them all when one central button is beeing pressed. My idea was to call all those reset() functions in a function that is located in a service. The problem with that approach is that I don't know how I can call this reset functions. All the examples I found have been with data but in my case I just want to call the components functions without sending data. Other approaches how to handel a central reset are also welcome [schematic idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8KEK.png)

Here is a minimal code example. It does not work properly because of some import problems but at least you can see the code. Hope it is okay anyways https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vp2cjo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fname%2Fname.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schematic idea is fine, you need to create a service like :

```
export class myService {
  reset: boolean = false;

  private emitChangeSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.reset);
  changeEmitted$ = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

  emitChange(change: any) {
    this.emitChangeSource.next(change);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

And then, you subscribe in your components like :

```
this.myService.changeEmitted$.subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
        this.form.reset();
    }
 });
```

To fire the change you use:

```
this.myService.emitChange(true);
```

Comment: I would caution against using behavior subject in this instance as it retains the previously emitted value. for events where you want to be notified of the event when it happens and not retain it's value for all time, i.e. the use clicks the reset button, a Subject might be a better fit. Unless, you actually have to deal with late subscribers of course.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I was stuck with the idea that I would have to call the reset function in another component instead of triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100 % sure if this helps you, but I know a way to call a function from another component.
With Viewchild you can't access function directly, but you can access variables, so my solution would be to set a lampda function into a variable that calls your reset function.
example displaying component

```
public resetCommand = () => {this.reset()}
```

example controling compontent

```
Viewchild ... myDisplay
callingReset()
{
    this.myDisplay['resetCommand']();
}
```